# Django search box on separate page from results

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I have a search box in my django site that's code looks like this:

```
<li>
    <i class="search fa fa-search search-btn"></i>
    <form action="" method="get" class="search-open">
        <div class="input-group animated fadeInDown">
            <input id="searchfield" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchfield">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="searchbutton" class="btn-u" type="button">Go</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

I need to submit this search form and have it go through a Django view but it wont cooperate.  I've tried a few methods but I can only seem to get things to work if the page displaying results is the same page where the search form is which is not the case here.

Any help or suggestions would help a ton.  I have a search function and everything and a template to display things but I need to redirect to /search-results preferably using `{% url 'search-results' %}`

EDIT:

I tried putting `{% templatetag openblock %}url 'search-results'{% templatetag closeblock %}` in the form's action but I get an error page not found because it renders the url like this:  127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'search-results%20%25%7D?q=QUERYGOESHERE  this would work perfect if it would actually access the correct view by using a good url, i don't know how to get it to use the django template tags and not create a retarded url string.  If I just do `{% url 'search-results` %}` I get an error so I have to escape them that way at least.  I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the form action to just `/search-results/` rather than use the shortcut `{% url 'search-results' %}`

Answer (score 1):

type in js file

```
var submit=document.querySelector('#searchbutton');
var input=document.querySelector('#searchfield');
submit.addEventListener("click",calc,false);

function calc(){
    var b = input.value; 
    """set value of b equal to input in searchfield"""
    var a = [];
    a.push(b);
    """to store value of b in array a"""
    document.getElementById('searchfield').value="";
    """to set value of searchfield to blank"""
    b.clear();
}
```